# Add geo-location data to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, geopy

I'm importing a CSV into a pandas data frame, and then I'm trying to create three new columns in that data frame from data retrieved from `geopy.geocoders.GoogleV3()` :

```
import pandas from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

DATA = pandas.read_csv("file/to/csv") 
geolocator = GoogleV3()

DATA.googleaddress, (DATA.latitude, DATA.longitude) = geolocator.geocode(DATA.address)
```

Problem is I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Path/To/GeoCoder.py", line 9, in <module>
    DATA.googleaddress, (DATA.latitude, DATA.longitude) = geolocator.geocode(DATA.address)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

What does this error mean and how do I get around it?

Comment: Have you verified that the DATA data frame has data?

Comment: Yes indeed several times :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `geolocator.geocode` expects a single argument at a time, not a list (or array).

You could try:

```
locs = [ geolocator.geocode(addr) for addr in DATA.address ]
geo_info = pandas.DataFrame(
    [ (addr.address, addr.latitude, addr.longitude) for addr in locs ],
    columns=['googleaddress', 'latitude', 'longitude'])
```

All you would have to do is merge these DataFrames:

```
DATA.combine_first(geo_info)
```

Nnote that it is considered [bad form](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to have an all-uppercase variable in python.

Comment: Well alright that did something!  Thanks, but now I get an error: 'too many variables to unpack' ... guessing it's because I'm passing too many addresses?  but it's only 27 for now...

Comment: No, it's because you have a list of 27 `Location` instances, that you're trying to [unpack](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#tut-unpacking-arguments) to 2 elements (one of which, a tuple). I'll update the answer.